# Proper order of additional components?

Tags: water, valve, heat-pump, floorheating, expansion-tank

I have this heat pump unit that has some features but unfortunately, some stuff in it is weak so the manufacturer's guide suggests I boost it a bit from the outside. Therefore I would like to add orange components in this particular order:

[image]

Could this be considered a good order?

- added expansion vessel is bigger based on the proper calculation
- added safety valve is 0.5 bar smaller (just to be safe - not really sure if it makes sense but the guide says that the maximum allowed operating pressure should be 3 bar but there is no mention of what should be the optimal/real pressure)
- and added a non-return valve because why not I guess

**My logic behind it:**

As the water heats up in the tank, due to increased pressure the volume of water rises and fills in internal and external expansion vessels to counter-balance the pressure buildup. Gradually as pressure rises and reaches a critical point of 2.5 bar it will trigger the external safety valve and the pressure rise will be halted by releasing the needed amount of water down the drain. if by any chance the external safety valve dies, the pressure will increase to 3 bar and the internal safety valve will activate to save the day

Comment: So to be clear, all the stuff you're planning to mess with is on the WATER side of the system, am I correct?   Because people will yell at you for messing with refrigerant, you need all manner of qualifiecation to do that per the Kyoto Protocol.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica yes, waterside as per the installation guide (the only thing that the installation guide does not contain is the proper order of additional stuff). a closed loop of underfloor heating. no way I will touch the refrigerant side with R32 coolant in it, which boils at -51°C and freezes at -136°C